# ReactJS - How to deserialize and show a serialized JSON response?

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, axios

I'm getting a serialized JSON body from our API like the below example: '

```
{
"_embedded": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "vulnerable": false,
        "systemId": "something",
        "friendlyName": "a friendly name"
    },

 ]
}
```

How to show just the key/value `friendlyName`? I'm using axios to get the response. This is my code:

```
 axios.get(BASE_URL + 'household/list',{
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
        transformResponse: axios.defaults.transformResponse.concat((data) => {
        console.log(data) // this should now be JSON
        })
    }).then(({ data })=> {
       this.setState({
                data: houses.friendlyName
            });
        })
        .catch((err)=> {
        console.log(err);
        });
```

I think I'm supposed to transform the data, but I don't know how. Thanks for any help.

Edit: This is how the response is shown in console:

```
_embedded:
   0:
    friendlyName: "a friendly name"
    id: 1
    systemId: "GE8BP2IACH7"
    vulnerable: false
```

So, how do I deserialize it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 axios.get(BASE_URL + 'household/list',{
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },

    }).then(function (response) {
    this.setState({data:response._embedded.friendlyName})
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: It's not working. I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property '_embedded' of undefined`.

Comment: please add console.log(data)

Comment: I update my answer, please do something like I print

Comment: I think it is the serialization that is creating the problem. I'm updating my question with what I see in the console as `response`.

Comment: you no need to transform it, just use object in response.